# how to append String To Mutable string

Tags: iphone

Hi i am new to iphone development,can any one help how to append string to mutable string.
 im trying to string By appending String Format .application Is crashes...

Comment: Can you add the code that crashes to the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sample code NSMutableString:

```
NSMutableString* mutString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(int index=0;index<10;index++)
    {
        [mutString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Content in MutableString: %@",mutString);
```

Regarding crash: post your code that crashes. What does it say ?

Comment: appendFormat is also possible

Answer (score 1):

There is a crash when you try to append nil to a `NSMutableString` - check that.
Also while it does not crash during append - if your `NSMutablestring` is not initialized - then nothing works and your app might crash later in the code because there is nothing in your string.
Post the crash report, I am sure it will tell you what is going wrong.